# impala sql only choose numbers of certain length

Tags: sql, cloudera, impala

I have a variable that was used as a free-txt field, thousands of rows long.

While it should contain only account numbers, it also contains phone numbers,  text, or NULL.

I need to extract columns with account numbers (8 digit fields) only. 
How can I archive this in SQL impala, especially as we not only have numbers, but also text. 
Also I need to know the percentage of account numbers vs others to estimate the time needed to fix the other fields. 
How can this be done?
 it would look something like this:

```
accounts
---------
12345678
23456789
test only
34567890
23443256
23443257
021735547
23443258
23443259
23443260
call back
23443261
53443262
23443263
23443264
23443265
cancel
53443262
53443263
63443264
53443265
73443266
53443267
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting.  I would use `regexp_like()`:

```
select sum(case when regexp_like(col, '^[0-9]{8}$') then 1 else 0 end) as cnt,
       avg(case when regexp_like(col, '^[0-9]{8}$') then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is good for this. Try:

```
select regexp_extract(free_text_column, '^[0-9]{8}$',1) from your_table
```

To get the precentage you can do

```
select count(regexp_extract(free_text_column, '^[0-9]{8}$',1))/count(*)
from your_table
```

You may need to cast the counts as float in order to get the division to work.